# recursion in sorted double linked list insertion

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, doubly-linked-list, insertion

I'm new to the data structures and recursion concept. I'm struggling to understand why and who he was able to use the recursion in this concept. I found this code in the forums for this and I couldn't really understand the concept of this. For simple case of 2 1 3 4, if any one can explain the iteration steps, it will be greatly appreciated on my behalf.

Here is the link for hacker rank: 
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/insert-a-node-into-a-sorted-doubly-linked-list

```
Node SortedInsert(Node head,int data) {
    Node n = new Node();
    n.data = data;
    if (head == null) {
        return n;
    }
    else if (data <= head.data) {
        n.next = head;
        head.prev = n;
        return n;
    }
    else {
        Node rest = SortedInsert(head.next, data);
        head.next = rest;
        rest.prev = head;
        return head;
    }
}
```

Comment: Erase this code from your brain and never revisit it.  This leaks like crazy and risks a stack overflow on long lists.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion:
Recursion means a function calls itself. It is used as a simple way to save state information for algorithms that require saving of multiple states, usually a large number of states, and retrieving them in reverse order. (There are alternative techniques that are more professional and less prone to memory issues, such as using a Stack object to save program state).

This example is poor but typical of intro to recursion. Yes, you can iterate through a linked list using recursion but there is absolutely no reason to. A loop would be more appropriate. This is purely for demonstrating how recursion works. So, to answer your question "Why?" it is simply so you can learn the concept and use it later in other algorithms that it actually makes sense.

Recursion is useful when instead of a linked list you have a tree, where each node points to multiple other nodes. In that case, you need to save your state (which node you are on, and which subnode you called last) so that you can traversing one of the linked nodes, then return and go to the next node.

You also asked "how". When a function calls itself, all of its variables are saved (on the program stack) and new ones are created for the next iteration of itself. Then, when that call returns, it goes back to where it was called from and the previous set of variables are loaded. This is very different from a "jump" or a loop of some kind, where the same copies of the variables are used each time. By using recursion, there is a new copy of every local variable each time it is called. This is true even of the "data" variable in the example, which never changes (hence, one inefficiency).

Comment: Thanks Garr. I appreciate your response and comments. It made sense. I will read more material about this. I would like to do more examples on recursion just get a grasp of the concept, so that I can debug and iterate on see myself what can happen. Can you suggest some examples like that? I have tried recursion on factorial and fibonnaci series.

Comment: here's an interesting one. Think about x^N as a recursive problem. Sure, you could loop 1..N, which is N multiplications, but you can do it with fewer by breaking the problem down because x^N = x^(N/2) * x^(N-(N/2)). You can recursively call for each side (or just one if N is even) and multiply the results. Must special case N=0,N=1 and maybe N=2